# How can I change the x-axis title using barplot from the enrichplot package?

Tags: r, plot

I am doing a `GO` enrichment analysis using the R package `clusterProfiler` and I want to visualize my results.

I saw that it is common to use `barplot` from the `enrichplot` package to do this, and actually I have tried and it is what I want.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to change the title of the x-axis, since I have checked the parameters and other posts and I have not found any way to do it.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Reproducible example:

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(enrichplot)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)

data(geneList, package="DOSE")
gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]


ego <- enrichGO(gene          = gene,
                universe      = names(geneList),
                OrgDb         = org.Hs.eg.db,
                ont           = "CC",
                pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                pvalueCutoff  = 0.01,
                qvalueCutoff  = 0.05,
                readable      = TRUE)

barplot(ego, showCategory = 5, cluster = "hierarchical", title = "GO Cellular Component",
        x = "Count")
```

[image]

- I would like to change "Count" for "Number of genes"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with `+ labs(x = "Number of genes")`. Not tested but according to the docs `enrichplot` builds on ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It gives me this error: `Error in labs(x = "Number of genes") : could not find function "labs"`

Comment: Did you load ggplot2 ? `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: Oh right. My bad. It works perfectly! Problem solved. Thanks very much to both of you!

Comment: @stefan Would you like to write your solution as the answer of my question? Your solution works perfectly